# Сетка с координатами JS

Tags: javascript, for, grid

Вот что состряпал, но работает не так, как надо. Подскажите где косяк.

```js
var _text1 = "";
var _text2 = "";
var _text3 = "";
var _my;
var _mx;

for (_my = -8; _my < 16; _my++) {

    _text1 = "<div class='tr'>";

    for (_mx = -22; _mx < 10; _mx++) {

        _text2 += "<div class='td'>" + _mx + "_" + _my + "</div>";
    }
    _text3 = "</div>";

    map.innerHTML += _text1 + _text2 + _text3;
}
```

```css
.table {
    display: table;
}

.tr {
    display: table-row;
}

.td {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='table' id='map'>
</div>
```

подскажите, где промахнулся... заранее спасибо

Comment: Первое: Зачем вам координаты в таблице? Можете, пожалуйста, уточнить суть задачи?

Comment: Второе, вам следует почитать про document.createElement() and nodeElement.append()

Comment: Первое: есть карта, на которой есть координаты. первый for это координаты по горизонтали, второй for это координаты по вертикали.

Comment: Карта для чего?

Comment: карта земли, расположение полей. координаты должны быть именно такими

Comment: @ntym: все эти уточнения должны быть изначально в вопросе. Если Вам действительно нужен ответ, тогда предоставляйте больше информации и конкретизируйте проблему. "Аааа!!! Не работает!.." - не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let map = document.querySelector(".map");

for(let y = -8; y<= 8;y++){
   let divY= document.createElement("div");
   divY.classList.toggle("coordinate_y");
   for(let x = -22; x <= 11; x++){
      let divX = document.createElement("div");
      divX.classList.toggle("coordinate_x");
      //divX.innerText = `x: ${x} y: ${y}`
      divY.append(divX);
   }
   map.append(divY);
}
```

```css
.coordinate_x{
min-width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:red;
border:1px solid black;
font-size:10px;
}
.coordinate_y{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class ="map"></div>
```

Если будете загружать фото карты, рекомендую использовать canvas

Comment: это вот так? <convas class ="map"></convas> или это не только html?

Comment: @ntym это не только html. Держи: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API